# Mongoose Save: Document failed validation, but console.log and manual insert is accepted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I'm working on some signup code (MERN stack) and I'm getting "Document failed validation" from MongoDB when using the user.save. However, it is accepted if I use console.log(), copy/paste the result into an insert, and replace the single quotes with double quotes.

Here is my signup route so far:

```
router.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
        let { firstName,
            lastName,
            profileImage,
            email,
            subscribed_Comments,
            subscribed_NewPost,
            username,
            password } = req.body;

        if (username && email && password && firstName && lastName && subscribed_Comments !== undefined && subscribed_NewPost !== undefined) {
            username = username.toLowerCase();
            email = email.toLowerCase();
            //Validate Password
            if (/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,15}$/.test(password)) {
                //Check if username or email already used
                User.findOne({ "$or": [{ "username": username }, { "email": email }] })
                    .exec((err, user) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                            res.status(500).send({ "error": "An unexpected error occurred. Please contact an administrator." });
                        } else if (user === null) {
                            //User did not exist ... create
                            bcrypt.genSalt(Number(SALT), function (err, salt) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.error(err);
                                    res.status(500).send({ "error": "An unexpected error occurred. Please contact an administrator." });
                                }
                                bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function (err, hash) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        console.error(err);
                                        res.status(500).send({ "error": "An unexpected error occurred. Please contact an administrator." });
                                    }
                                    //create user
                                    let user = new User({
                                        username: username,
                                        email: email,
                                        password: hash,
                                        userRole: "User"
                                    });
                                    console.log(user)
                                    user.save((err, user) => {
                                        if (err) {
                                            console.error(err);
                                            res.status(500).send({ "error": "Failed to create a User. Please contact an administrator." });
                                        } else {
                                            console.log(`Successfully created user ${user.username}`);
                                            //create account
                                            let account = new Account({
                                                "FirstName": firstName,
                                                "LastName": lastName,
                                                "SubscribedNewPost": subscribed_NewPost,
                                                "SubscribedComments": subscribed_Comments,
                                                "ProfileImage": profileImage || "",
                                                "User_Account": user._id
                                            });
                                            account.save((err, account) => {
                                                if (err) {
                                                    console.error(err);
                                                    user.delete();
                                                    res.status(500).send({ "error": "Failed to create an Account. Please contact an Administrator" });
                                                } else {
                                                    console.log(`Successfully created account for ${account.firstName} ${account.lastName}`);
                                                    req.session.userid = user._id;
                                                    req.session.username = user.username;
                                                    req.session.userRole = user.userRole;
                                                }
                                            })
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        } else {
                            console.log(`Username: ${username} or Email: ${email} already in use.`);
                            res.status(500).send({ "error": "Username or Email is already in use" });
                        }
                    });
            } else {
                // Invalid Password
                console.log("Invalid Password in Signup");
                res.status(500).send({ "error": "Password did not meet expected criteria" });
            }
        } else {
            res.status(500).send({ "error": "Invalid Request" });
        }
    })
```

Here is the Mongoose Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: [true, "That username already registered."],
    required: [true, "Username is required."]
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: [true, "That email is already registered."],
    required: [true, "Email is required."],
    validate: {
        validator: function(v){
            return /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/i.test(v);
        },
        message: "Email was not in a valid format."
    }    
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Password is required."]
  },
  userRole: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["Anonymous", "User", "Moderator"],
      required: [true, "User Role is required."]
  }
}, {collection: "User"}, {versionKey: false})

module.exports = mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
```

Here is the MongoDB Validation

```
{
  $jsonSchema: {
    bsonType: 'object',
    title: 'user',
    required: [
      'username',
      'email',
      'password',
      'userRole'
    ],
    properties: {
      _id: {
        bsonType: 'objectId',
        uniqueItems: true
      },
      username: {
        bsonType: 'string',
        uniqueItems: true
      },
      email: {
        bsonType: 'string',
        uniqueItems: true,
        pattern: '^\\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$'
      },
      password: {
        bsonType: 'string'
      },
      userRole: {
        'enum': [
          'Anonymous',
          'User',
          'Moderator'
        ]
      }
    },
    additionalProperties: false
  }
}
```

Here is the json that fails validation (from the console.log()). If I copy/paste this and replace the single quotes with double quotes then mongodb accepts it.

```
{
  _id: 606a0a09d70db426acda05ee,
  username: 'johndoe',
  email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
  password: '$2b$10$vofYCj31690seAIKHqjkUuba8paeJy5ZC1Qt8ZHjZHmKVQurZ.hfi',       
  userRole: 'User'
}
```

Any thoughts on why the above would fail validation when it is following my defined schema? I've tried removing the validation from the Mongoose schema to make sure its not failing there and it wasn't. The only left I think it could be would be it doesn't format of the _id, but it wouldn't make sense that mongodb would reject the default _id created by mongoose.

Edit: Here is the stack trace

```
MongoError: Document failed validation
    at Function.create (D:\Projects\portfolio-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\error.js:57:12)
    at toError (D:\Projects\portfolio-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:123:22)
    at D:\Projects\portfolio-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\common_functions.js:265:39
    at handler (D:\Projects\portfolio-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:942:24)
    at D:\Projects\portfolio-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:350:13
    at handleOperationResult (D:\Projects\portfolio-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\server.js:558:5)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (D:\Projects\portfolio-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:277:5)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at processIncomingData (D:\Projects\portfolio-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (D:\Projects\portfolio-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:442:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:426:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:317:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:695:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12) {
  driver: true,
  name: 'MongoError',
  index: 0,
  code: 121
}
```

Comment: Can you copy the Validation error here?

Comment: Yeah my bad haha. I've edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out. Apparently, Mongoose Schema adds the __v integer to the .save call despite my having versionKey: false in the schema. I tested it by setting the validation to warning instead of error and observed the __v appearing in the documents that got saved. To fix it, I added the following to the Validation JSON in mongo.

```
  __v: {
    bsonType: 'int'
  }
```

TLDR: The "validation" that was missing was the __v property not being defined while 'additionalProperties' was set to false.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably because of the `_id`. You are sending the string representation of the `ObjectId`, but the `_id` required type is `ObjectId`. Try to replace the `_id: 606a0a09d70db426acda05ee` with the `_id:ObjectId('606a0a09d70db426acda05ee')`;

Also you can try to change this:

```
let user = new User({
  username: username,
  email: email,
  password: hash,
});
console.log(user)
user.save((err, user) => {
```

With this:

```
User.create({
  username: username,
  email: email,
  password: hash,
}).then((user)=>{
   console.log('User successfully created: ', user);
}, (error)=>{
   console.log('ERROR: ', error);
})
```